# Как на Java передать исключение наверх?

Tags: исключения, java

Например, нижеприведенный код выведет только "1":

```
public void foo() {
    int a = 5;
    try {
        try {
        a /= 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
```

А как передать исключение из внутреннего блока на внешний, т.е. чтобы результат был:

```
1
2
```

Comment: } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(1);
            throw e;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто throw то же исключение из catch.

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Throwable t) {
   ...
   throw t;
}
```

а можно кинуть новое

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Throwable t) {
   ...
   throw new RuntimeException(t);
}
```

преобразовав тип исключения

Comment: А почему Вы пишите Throwable t, вместо например, Exception t? Чем Throwable t лучше?

Comment: Throwable это базовый класс, от котрого наследуются остальные исключения. 

Возможно правильнее как раз перехватывать отдельно Exception и Error, наследуемые от Throwable. 

Вообще см. [оригинал](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html).

Comment: - `Throwable,` насколько мне известно, имеет смысл перехватывать только в том случае, если у метода должна быть настоящая `strong nothrow guarantee` по контракту и, в общем, стоит сто раз подумать перед тем, как делать это.

- Поскольку `Throwable` включает в себя множество исключений, не предусматривающих `graceful` восстановления (типа `OutOfMemoryException`), то, в общем, необходимость их перехвата представляется сомнительной.

Comment: @avp, мне хотелось бы увидеть действия при отловле Error(обработка, при возникновении ошибки), возникновение которого обычно садит весь jvm. Отлавливать Error считаю неразумным.

Comment: @Viacheslav, если не хотите обрабатывать, киньте дальше

    try {
        ...
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof Error)
            throw t;
        ....
    }

или если Вы считаете вообще неразумным ловить Error, то не ловите Throwable, а только Exception. Конечно, если в Вашей программе что-то унаследовано от Throwable кроме Error и Exception, то ловите и эти новые исключения. 

(еще раз, см. **документацию по Java** (в моем преыдущем комментарии)).

Comment: @avp, я повторюсь еще раз - если возникает Error - jvm ложится, и выполнение любого кода прекращается. И если вы посмотрите чуть-чуть дальше по той ссылке на документацию что Вы дали, то всё поймете [Error javadoc][1]


  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

Comment: @Viacheslav, скажите прямо - чего Вы хотите? Не связываться с Error, не связывайтесь, тогда **не перехватывайте** Throwable.

Вы считаете, что нижний уровень перехватываемых исключений это Exception? Не буду спорить, на самом деле многие пишут так.

Но, Error - Error-у рознь. Вы и сами можете его сгенерить в любой момент или можете создать новый класс унаследованный от Error.

--

У Вас возникает ситуация в которой падает jvm? Пишите код, отслеживая все аргументы всего, что может завалить jvm или пишите на другом языке (правда отслеживать корректность данных все равно придется (*rm -R /*)).